# Jquery Multiple Forms

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm new to JQuery and I can't believe this isn't possible...

I have multiple HTML forms which are dynamically created. I'm using JQuery to capture the data from the forms but when I submit the form all I can access is the data from the last form.

Here is my code:

```
for($x=0; $x<10; $x++){

     ?>
     <form method="POST" id="formid<? echo $x; ?>">
      <textarea name="notes_text"><? echo $row[2]; ?></textarea></td>
      <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $row[0]; ?>" name="notes_id" />
      <input type="image" src="/images/edit-small.png" id="update-notes-submit" class="submit-img-sml"/>            
     </form>
     <?

}
```

and the jQuery:

```
$("form").submit(function(){

     var form_id = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');  
     alert(form_id);

     var notes_id=$('#formid1 input[name=notes_id]').val();
     var notes_text=$('#formid1 textarea[name=notes_text]').val();

}
```

The alert gives me the correct formid so that works.

If I alert the notes_id or notes_text variables I get 'undefined'.

I have tried:

```
var notes_id=$('#formid1 input[name=notes_id]').val();
= undefined

var notes_id=$('#formid2 input[name=notes_id]').val();
= undefined

var notes_id=$('input[name=notes_id]').val();
= data from the last form that appears in my script
```

How do I specify the form and the variable. I can't believe this is so difficult to achieve, perhaps this is not possible with JQuery and if so it's a shocking limitation.

Comment: Why can't you just reference the form data in the submit? Isn't it possible to do: `$("form").submit(function(data)` where data is the values you are trying to get to via selectors?

Comment: You have a `</td>` after `</textarea>`. That's matching a `<td>` outside the form, so the form element is being terminated as well. As a result, the `<input>` elements are not within the form. Take a look at the DOM in the inspector and you'll see how messed up this is.

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming that the form id is `formid1` but I have a feeling that is not the one being submitted.  Try the following:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
     var form =$(this);//this refers to the form
     var notes_id=form.find('input[name=notes_id]').val();
     var notes_text=form.find('textarea[name=notes_text]').val();
 }
```

Comment: I think he is missing quotes in his syntax, as are you.

Comment: He said `The alert gives me the correct formid so that works.` BTW. So while I think your suggestion may still be correct, if the id is right, how could it be referring to the wrong form?

Comment: @Leeish - I'm thinking he may have missed the fact he was hard coding the form id in the selectors... there are 10 forms on the page so his code was only going to work for the form with the id of formid = 1

Comment: Ah.. I was thinking he hardcoded the formid in there for testing purposes. You are probably correct. I'm still pissed about the quotes.

Comment: The suggested code gives the same outout: undefined. I am getting the correct id from the relevant form because the output of the following is correct: alert($(this).closest("form").attr('id')); I just cannot qualify one form id over another!

Comment: Justin I get same problem with your code, I pasted it into my script and also got 'undefined' and 'undefined'. I'm not sure it's possible to handle dynamic form in JQuery...

Comment: @user2056238 it definitely is possible.  there is something else going on.

Comment: @user2056238 If you haven't already seen Barmar's answer - that is the reason your code isn't working

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I finally figured it out after about 8 hours of hammering away.

The problem was caused by the table tags which were in the wrong place. I was using this format:

```
<table>

 <?

 for($x=1; $x<=mysql_num_rows($notes); $x++){

      $row=mysql_fetch_row($notes);

      ?>
      <form id="form<? echo $x; ?>">

       <tr>
        <td width="150"><b>Text 1</b></td>
        <td colpsan="3"><textarea name="txtarea">Some text</textarea></td>
       </tr>

      <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $row[0]; ?>" name="notes_id" />        
      </form>

      <?

 }

?>

</table>
```

But if I placed the table opening and closing tags within the for loop it solved the problem:

```
 <?

 for($x=1; $x<=mysql_num_rows($notes); $x++){

      $row=mysql_fetch_row($notes);

      ?>

      <table>
       <form id="form<? echo $x; ?>">

        <tr>
         <td width="150"><b>Text 1</b></td>
         <td colpsan="3"><textarea name="txtarea">Some text</textarea></td>
        </tr>

       <input type="hidden" value="<? echo $row[0]; ?>" name="notes_id" />        
       </form>

      </table> 

      <?       

}

?>
```

I'm not sure why this works, because as far as I can see this simply creates a table for each form, where as previously a single table was used.

Thank you so much for your help - it is appareciated!

Comment: Don't forget to mark this or any of the other answers to this question as "accepted", see [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187921) for more information. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extraneous `</td>` after `</textarea>`.  It's matching a  outside the form, so the form element is being terminated as well. As a result, the  elements are not within the form. Take a look at the DOM in the inspector and you'll see how messed up this is.

Answer (score -3):

Aren't you missing quotes?

```
var notes_id=$('#formid1 input[name=notes_id]').val();
var notes_text=$('#formid1 textarea[name=notes_text]').val();

var notes_id=$('#formid1 input[name="notes_id"]').val();
var notes_text=$('#formid1 textarea[name="notes_text"]').val();
```

Pretty sure those quotes matter.

Comment: WTF, so quotes never matter when using selectors like that. Why the hell not.

Comment: Yes. I am. I don't like it when things are accepted in more than one way, or are seemingly inconsistent. Reminds me too much of PHP.

Comment: Are the quotes needed when using this type of selector in CSS?

Comment: Quotes are needed if the value after `=` contains special characters, e.g. `]`.

Comment: Things I never knew I didn't know.